# Can't access Internal SD Card

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-sd

I can't access the internal SD Card (8GB) on my Wayteq x-tab 80, with Android 4.
The device is not rooted, and worked perfectly fine until yesterday. I could access the SD card from the tablet, and also from my PC when connected with USB. Now it doesn't work either way.
I checked in the Settings, and it seems like the SD Card is Unmounted, but even after clicking on Mount it doesn't do anything.
I did a factory reboot, it didn't help.

I'm not a tech expert, so I can't figure out what's the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to rule out human errors due to panic, could you try downloading some file? If you can then your device's internal storage is intact and system is able to access. May be it will throw some light on what else could be wrong.

Comment: Has the SD card been removed at all during this time? Are you able to try the SD card in a different device to make sure it's not at fault?

Comment: I tried to download files, it says that "an SD card is required to download [file name]"

Comment: It's an internal SD card, so no, it hasn't been removed. The tablet is only 2 weeks old so I would rather not try to remove it, also I have no other device to put it in.

Comment: This is not a solution to your question, but a way to keep your device working till you get it repaired. Buy another micro SD card and insert into the device slot. This will make the device to start using the new card as its storage and you will be able to start using the tablet.

Comment: Narayanan: Thanks, that was my intention if I can't figure out how to repair the internal SD card. I'm just hoping that the tablet will recognize the external card.

Comment: Aside from Narayanan's suggested work-around, I'd return the device to the vendor for either repair or replacement. Unless you'd explicitly run some root-exploit or the like (which might have messed things up), a no-longer-working internal storage is nothing a user action could have caused, so it should fall under warranty.

Comment: Izzy: Yeah, I think that is the best option right now. Thanks.

Comment: I think to really get it right, it unfortunately most likely is the only option. Crossing fingers for your replacement! If your vendor offers some more explanation, please make sure to let us know. Thanks!

Comment: How did it work out? The solution might be helpful to other users which might be affected of a similar problem.

Comment: I do not have an answer but I have the same problem. Did you ever get an answer that worked? My SD card mounts then randomly unmounts leaving me with the only choice of reinstalling the ROM. Then the sdcard is recognized for a short period of time until the tablet fails once more to recognize it. I also get the message that sdcard is solely occupied by the computer.

Comment: Are you talking about internal flash memory or an SD card that you added to your device? These are two distinctly different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 recovery softwares to recover data from a damaged partition table if this is the case:

http://www.recovermyfiles.com/data-recovery-software-download.php

http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Media device (MTP) option is disabled. Make sure that this is enabled, you would find this under the menu option "USB computer connection" in Settings > Device > Storage. Also make sure that "USB debugging" is disabled in Settings > System > Developer options.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether the storage is working by using usb debugging no matter whether device is rooted or not by entering the list command to see whether the storage is readable.

```
adb shell
ls /sdcard
```

make a folder in it using this command:

```
mkdir /sdcard/Example
```

and list it again:

```
ls /sdcard
```

If the folder Example shows up never worry because this a small issue. After that you can look for twrp and go to wipe, advanced, repair partition after checking the /sdcard